# Build a Collapsed tree using Stanfrod Parser in Python

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm following this [tutorial](https://sci1.uk/coding/stanford-nltk/) to build a dependency tree for a sentence using Python. The tutorial shows how to use Stanfrod Parser with NLTK. I'm already past this step and I can build the tree as shown in my code below.

```
from config import config 
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
class ExtractTree:

def __init__(self):
    """
    Init Stanford parse tree
    """
    path_to_jar = config['libs_root'] + "stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17/stanford-parser.jar"
    path_to_models_jar = config['libs_root'] + "stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17/stanford-parser-3.9.2-models.jar"

    self.dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(
        path_to_jar=path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar,java_options=[]
    )

def extract_tree(self, sentence):
    """
    Extract the dependency tree for a sentence
    :param sentence:
    :return:
    """
    result = self.dependency_parser.raw_parse(sentence)

    return next(result)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to build a collapsed dependency tree as described in here: [image] (the image and the quote are from [Stanford Parser Documentation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) page.20)

> In the collapsed representation, dependencies involving prepositions, conjuncts, as well as information
>   about the referent of relative clauses are collapsed to get direct dependencies between content words.

It seems java has an API for it but I cannot find a way to integrate that in Python, any ideas?

Comment: You are saying that you are following this tutorial but you do not say where you get stuck? Where is the image from that you posted? Can you please clarify the relation between your question and the tutorial.